# XCUITest - UISlider shows up as "Other", unable to perform adjustToNormalizedSliderPosition

Tags: ios, uislider, xcode-ui-testing

I have a tableview cell containing some labels and a uislider subclass.
However, the slider is not recognized as a slider type, but as 'Other'.

Inspecting the view, the Accessibility prints:

```
Is Accessibility Element
Value 0% Adjustable Trait On
Elements <null>
Description ageSlider
Hint <null>
Identifier  <null>
Custom Action  <null> Not Focused
```

Any ideas how to let XCUITest recognize my slider as, you know, a slider?

This is the tree printed by XCode for the tableview cell:

```
Cell 0x7ff9c2bb95c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 203.1}, {375.0, 95.0}}, identifier: \'SliderCell\'
    StaticText 0x7ff9c2bb9d70: traits: 8589934656, {{19.0, 219.1}, {205.0, 18.0}}, label: \'Select minimum age\'
    StaticText 0x7ff9c2bba4c0: traits: 8589934656, {{210.0, 219.1}, {145.0, 18.0}}, label: \'Any\'

    Other 0x7ff9c2bbabf0: traits: 8589938688, {{33.0, 248.1}, {309.0, 34.0}}, identifier: \'ageSlider\', value: 0%
```

Comment: What's the output when you try to use `adjustToNormalizedSliderPosition`?

Comment: @Oletha An error message this method cannot be executed on an element that is not a Slider